# jQuery AJAX problems, intermittently getting duplicate requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Right then, I'm coming to the end of a rewrite of our JavaScript system, we're moving from Prototype to jQuery. We have a load of AJAX requests that fire when a certain element events occur, the one in the example below is a new event on a calendar, but it happens elsewhere too.

The problem I'm getting is when an event is fired sometimes two AJAX requests are made. The first one returns the correct value but (as you can see) it still says processing, it never returns the success message my JavaScript requires. The second request returns the correct result AND terminates correctly.

The problem I have is our jQuery screen blocker is set up to prevent user input during heavy AJAX requests, obviously because there an AJAX request still live the screen never unlocks. If I were to refresh this screen all will work as desired.

Can anyone shed any light on why this behavior is occuring.

[alt text http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request.png](http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request.png)

**EDIT**

> "requests that fire when a certain element events occur" - this is the key phrase, I think. Please provide some info on how you set your events. Maybe it fires twice because you have multiple handlers set? – Igor Zinov'yev

Ok, the thing is when I hit refresh the problem usually resolves itself, so not sure how that could be a handler issue, here's the event handler we typically use for a change of a select box.

```
$("#my_select","#context").change(function(){
            // uz_ajax is a wrapper function, keeps most of the same functionality as $.ajax()
    uz_ajax({
        target:"#my_target",
        data:{
            module:'my_module',
            controller:'my_controller',
            action:'my_action',
            id:$(this).val(),
            ajax:''
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I have is I have no idea how to replicate the problem, so I do not know if the event is being fired multiple times or whether the AJAX is requesting twice.

**EDIT 2**

> If you are reloading the elements that
>   are bound then the change events could
>   be triggered recursively... We really
>   need to see more code (what do you do
>   on success of the ajax call etc) –
>   redsquare

Thanks redsquare, upon a successful AJAX request I usually apply the response (usually HTML of `<option>`s) to the target. I never trigger a change from the element that fired the AJAX, but I sometimes trigger a change on the target element, to allow for cascading AJAX requests. If this were the problem, surely this would happen all the time? My wrapper function `uz_ajax` is below:

```
var ajax_count = 0;
var ajax_response = null;

function uz_ajax(options) {

    // set default options
    var defaults = {
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        data: {},
        url: "/",
        cache: false,
        force_change: true,
        highlight: true,
        action: "normal",
        dataType: "html",
        selected: {
            value: null,
            disabled: false
        }
    };

    // merge the passed options with the defaults
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    // start the jQuery ajax method
    $.ajax({
        async: options.async,
        type: options.type,
        url: options.url,
        data: options.data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // we only want to block the screen on the first pass
            if(++ajax_count==1) {
                $.blockUI({message:'Loading data, please wait'});
            } 
        },
        success: function(responseText) {           
            if(options.target!==undefined) {
                // if target isn't an array, make it one
                if(!$.isArray(options.target)) {
                    options.target = new Array(options.target);
                }

                var targets = options.target;

                for ( var i in targets ) {
                    console_info("uz_ajax() --> Applying contents to "+targets[i]);

                    switch(options.action) {
                        case "normal":
                            if($(targets[i]).is("input")) {
                                $(targets[i]).val(trim(responseText));
                            } else {
                                $(targets[i]).html(trim(responseText));
                            }
                            break;
                        case "selected":
                            // preserve the current target value (e.g. list of options), but 
                            // set the selected value to the ajax response
                            console_warn("Changing selected value of "+targets[i]+" to '"+responseText+"'");
                            // trim the response so we don't get any smarty induced errors such as '    7'
                            $(targets[i]).val(trim(responseText));
                            break;
                    }

                    // set selected value
                    if(options.selected.value!=null) {
                        $(targets[i]).val(options.selected.value);
                    }

                    // highlight the target
                    // we don't want to highlight the target if it's a hidden input, as this will force a .show(
                    if($(targets[i]).attr('type')!='hidden' && options.highlight===true) {
                        $(targets[i]).effect("highlight",{},2000);
                    }

                    // force the target to change
                    if(options.force_change===true) {
                        $(targets[i]).trigger("change");    
                    }

                    /* rebind certain elements that do not use conventional events */
                    /* We probably need to get all of these rebinds in a single function */
                    createDatePickers(targets[i]);
                }
            } else {
                ajax_response = responseText;
                console_warn("uz_ajax -> no targets specified");
                // Well... we have no element to target, we need to return the value instead
                // of course if we return here we're going
                // we probably also need to check the ajax count as this will be the last executed part before we return
            }
        },
        complete: function () {
            /* if all ajax requests have completed, unblock screen */
            if(--ajax_count===0) {
                $.unblockUI();
                /* could use this callBack to return a value *dun dun duuuuun* */
                if (options.ajaxComplete) {
                    options.ajaxComplete(ajax_response);
                }
            }
        },
        cache: options.cache,
        dataType: options.dataType
    });

}
```

> another way to stop multiple ajax
>   requests is to heck jQuery.active
>   prior to the call. jQuery keeps an
>   internal count of 'live' ajax requests
>   using this property. – redsquare

I'll look into this.

**EDIT 3**

So this is the result of the $('element').data(), but I can't understand what it's trying to say, does this mean there are two binds to it. If so how do I find out what these binds are and why do they both not fire when the event is fired.

[alt text http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/firebug-jquery-data-events.png](http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/firebug-jquery-data-events.png)

**EDIT 4**

Here's another screenshot of the problem, this time in a different place in the system. The green arrow is the element thats triggers the three ajax requests, not in firebug how there's six, and that they pair up and share timestamps down to the millisecond?

The top three are the ones that have not completed, the bottom three have return the correct result.

[alt text http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v2.png](http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v2.png)

**EDIT 5**

The image below demonstrates what happens when a select box is changed, it fires **three** different ajax requests.

I've managed to do a bit more debugging and I can tell you the following:

1. The problem occurs regardless of how many ajax requests the initial element calls
2. The problem occurs regardless of what plugins are used
3. This event is definitely only being fired once
4. My uz_ajax wrapper function is only being fired once per target (see the firebug console, "Line 29: uz_ajax()".
5. I've added `console.info` on each of the jquery `$.ajax()` callbacks to see what's firing and when, notice how the only callback to fire is `beforeSend()`.

[alt text http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v3.png](http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v3.png)

**EDIT 6**

Right then, after @redsquare suggested via Twitter about using `console.trace()` to find out "where the second event is firing from" is, like I've always maintained I'm sure there isn't two events firing so I put the trace in the `$.ajax()` method, here's what happened:

[alt text http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v4.png](http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v4.png)

As you can see I get the duplicate ajax request problem even though the `$.ajax()` method has only fired once, again the timestamps are identical. Have I come across a bug with jQuery?

**EDIT 7**

It happens on StackOverflow too!

[alt text http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v5.png](http://archive.ilmv.co.uk/images/jquery-duplicate-ajax-request-v5.png)

Comment: "requests that fire when a certain element events occur" - this is the key phrase, I think. Please provide some info on how you set your events. Maybe it fires twice because you have multiple handlers set?

Comment: I'll add some more information in the **EDIT** at the end.

Comment: If you are reloading the elements that are bound then the change events could be triggered recursively...
We really need to see more code (what do you do on success of the ajax call etc)

Comment: another way to stop multiple ajax requests is to heck jQuery.active prior to the call. jQuery keeps an internal count of 'live' ajax requests using this property.

Comment: Cheers @redsquare, have another look at my question, I've responded under **EDIT 2** :-)

Comment: ILMV - could you humour me and unbind the change event prior to the ajax call and rebind the change at the end of the success callback. This should stop the changing of the options triggering another ajax request. I assume it happens once because the initial update changes the selectedIndex of the select but the next update does not...if you see what I mean

Comment: Hey redsqaure I thought I'd do the good thing and humour you, however I can only confirm that the problem still exists if I unbind() and rebind the event. I'm happy with this in a way, because there's no way I am going to unbind and rebind every single even in my system, there are just too many of them. Thanks for your suggestion though :-)

Comment: @ILMV - if you can open the app to the outside world I would be happy to try and debug it for you. Does the issue exist in chrome/ie also?

Comment: Could it be that you have bound the same event more than once. hard to tell as I cannot see the context where you bind your events. You can check the events bound to an element my saying $('#eleId').data('events')

Comment: This in an internal application so cannot open it up for two reasons... firewall not configured to let HTTP traffic in (whatever it needs to be) plus application has confidential data in. It's good to know about the data method to check what events are bound to it, I'll check and come back again.

Comment: I don't use Chrome as my dev browser, but I'll have a go to see if I can get it to freak out.

Comment: I've edited my post again, look under **EDIT 3**

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is 2 submit events on that element. Which element was it that you tested?

Comment: you will be able to see what events they are if you dont hook up anonymous events rather give them a real event handler .click( myClickFn )

Comment: you could try using .one to only bind the handler for one event. And rebind it when you need to. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: They all use the click (or the live('click'...), are you trying to say I change the name of function from function to "myClickEvent"... like this: `$('#element').click(myClickEvent() { });` ?

Comment: no need for the parens $('#element').click( myClickEvent );

Comment: it may help you to debug and click through in firebug rather than always seeing handler : function() you should get handler : myEvent or at least click the handler and see the event

Comment: Right I see what you mean, so myClickEvent is a function that performs the various tasks on that event. I can see it in firebug now :) Still have two events, need to track the other down.

Comment: ok good. Happy hunting for it! let me know how you go or if you need a hand

Comment: Thanks fro your help so far redsquare, I've discovered where the other event is but it certainly doesn't look likes it's interfering :S

Comment: I might resort to using console.logs in your code then you can hopefully pinpoint what event is triggering the second xhr call - or just debugger; statements prior to the ajax call and look at the stack trace in fb

Comment: Ah redsquare! Some information I've neglected to give you. In other parts of the system I have ajax requests that have cache set to false, this adds the timestamp in the url and when I get the problem both timestamps are identical... it would be unlikely that this would be the case if the ajax request were being fired from two different places (even if it's coming into the same event, it would be slightly later), the timestamps include milliseconds and they are both identical. Surely this must mean it's firing two ajax requests from the very same instance of the event?

Comment: could it be the line  $(targets[i]).val(trim(responseText));
You set the value which triggers the change events...you then also trigger the change event right after by doing  $(targets[i]).val(options.selected.value);

Comment: redsquare these do not trigger the change event, which is why further down I've got a condition that if the `force_change` option is true, we trigger the change. Plus there is never a case where the element that fires the ajax is it's own target. I've added another (better) example in my quesiton under **EDIT 4**, look how the timestamps are identical.

Comment: hmm, could be an issue in that for loop and createDatePickers(targets[i]); method. Maybe you need a closure here see http://joust.kano.net/weblog/archive/2005/08/08/a-huge-gotcha-with-javascript-closures/. As an aside you should cache the call to $(targets[i]) rather than creating the jq object multiple times.

Comment: Hey @redsquare, I've done a bit more digging and posted some edited information under **EDIT 5** if you've got a moment.

Comment: @ILMV what is the response on the ajax calls? Does the response contain any js?

Comment: Also, you have an event hooked to the select change, does the calendar widget also fire an event when a date changes which invokes another (or more) ajax calls?

Comment: Only pure HTML (e.g. a load of `<options>`), no JavaScript. The calendar plugin doesn't fire any ajax by itself, only the stuff I've programmed in, and I've only done one at the moment.

Comment: are you sure your dom validates, have you got any duplicate id's lying about. Test it at http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: The HTML is certainly not perfect, it doesn't validate (I'd like to take a hammer to it but I inherited this code and haven't had the chance to fix it all), but I have made sure there are no duplicate IDs.

Comment: JQuery does rely on a valid dom to work 100%, what type of validation errors are you getting

Comment: Errors such as element attributes that aren't allowed, like rel on `<li>` elements. I'm still not sure how that could cause an intermittent problem :S

Comment: And I've just made sure the code in this particular area validates 100% and I've just got the problem again.

Comment: Hey @redsquare I've added a bit more information under **EDIT 6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I've come to a conclusion, I'm pretty sure that my problem is an issue with Firebug, as I've tested it the app on FF without Firebug turned on and it works as it should do.

This isn't the first time something JavaScript related has led me on a merry dance when the symptoms thrown by the problem don't offer any reasonable hint to the solution, but there we have it.

Massive thanks to @redsquare, who's helped massively both here, but via twitter and the jQuery IRC channel, many thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a .click() instead? I have had issues with irregular activity using .change() in javascript. Give that a try.

Comment: Hello Phil :D, we need to use change for keyboard activity, and whilst this example uses the change event it happens on others too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `return false` to your onchange function.
This will stop jQuery from bubbling the event.

You should make sure that `$("#my_select","#context").change(function(){` is only called once.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the event bind is only called once, I'm sure of it.

Comment: Ah sorry I didn't get back to you on that one, this specific example (not the one I shown in the code) does have `return false;` and still the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [this](http://eligeske.com/jquery/jquery-sending-multiple-ajax-requests-all-by-itself-kind-of/):

```
$(selector).unbind().on(eventname,function(){
    $.ajax({
        //ajax code here
    });
});
```

It worked.

Comment: This was a long time ago now, but the issue wasn't jQuery making duplicate requests, but Firebug reporting duplicate requests.